# how to break this loop correctly

Tags: python

I'm a little lost on how to correct the below problem.
When the xxxx counter reaches 15, I want the script to stop, which works fine.
However, when there's an error in one of the try statements, I only want it to go to the next url in oldlist, not stop the script like it does right now.

I read the docs about this and the possible better inclusion of a While statement, but i'm not sure what to do here to make it work like I want it to. It's actually a lot bigger loop, but just simplified below.

system: IDLE on Python 2.7.* x64

```
xxxx = 0
oldlist = [lost of stuff]
newlist = [lots of stuff]
otherlist = [lots of stuff]

for url in oldlist:
    found = False

    if xxxx == 15:
        break

    for item in newlist:
        if something:
            if something:
                found = True

    for items in otherlist:
        if something:
            found = False

    if found == True:
        xxxx +=1

        try:
            something
        except Exception as thing: #catch em all
            print "1st Error"
            break    #should go to the next url

        try:
            something
        except Exception as morethings: #catch em all
            print "2nd Error"
            break    #should go to the next url
```

Is this actually bad python?
Should it be more like:

```
while xxxx != 15:
    for url in oldlist:
        found = False

        for item in newlist:
            if something:
                if something:
                    found = True

        for items in otherlist:
            if something:
                found = False

        while found == True:
            xxxx +=1

        while True:
            try:
                something
            except Exception as thing: #catch em all
                print "1st Error"
                break

            try:
                something
            except Exception as morethings: #catch em all
                print "2nd Error"
                break
```

Comment: Try to use `continue` in the `except` blocks instead of `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) in the `except` blocks instead of `break` to continue with the next item in your `for` loop, if any.

```
try:
    something
except Exception as thing:
    print "1st Error"
    continue    # go to the next url
```

Apart from that, your first code block looks okay. However, you might want to increment your counter *after* the `try/excepts`, otherwise those cases where you have an exception and skip to the next iterations are counted, too. But maybe that's just what you want.

Your second code block is semantically not equivalent, and IMHO also much less readable. This one will always go through the entire `for` loop and just then break from the `while` loop -- or even go through the `for` loop again if there were fewer than 15 'good' URLs in it. Also, both of the inner `while` loops are infinite loops (the first always, the second unless you have an exception and break out of it).

Comment: Lesson learned here, thought the continue statement did nothing more than jump to the next line...

Comment: @Ruud What do you mean, it jumped to the next line? Did the `continue` statement do nothing at all (i.e. skip to the next line of code)? Or did you mean the next item in your `for` loop (i.e. the next 'line' in some list of URLs)?

Comment: No, it worked perfect, but I implemented the continue statement incorrect the first time I tried it, so I didn't bother to test it further, hence my question here. I was on the right way after all.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you need the `continue` statement, rather than the `break` statement.

[Flow-control docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)